# Parsing Blocks of Data in REBOL

Tags: parsing, rebol

I have (games scores) data in this format:

> Hotspurs Giants         356  6   275   4   442   3
>
> Fierce Lions Club       371  3     2520   5        0   4
>
> Mountain Tigers        2519   2    291   6     342   1
>
> Shooting Stars Club   2430   5  339   1     2472   2
>
> Gun Tooters            329   4      2512   2      2470  6
>
> Banshee Wolves        301  1     2436   3      412   5

The first two/three words represent the club's names, thereafter follows 6 blocks of data per row which represents the club's round-by-round scores and opponent index (starting from 1). In the data above 3 rounds have been played by each team. *Hotspurs Giants* (index 1) played *Banshee Wolves* (6) in the 1st round scoring 356 to Banshee's 301, in round 2 *Hotspurs Giants* played *Shooting Stars Club* (4) scoring 275 - 339 and in round 3 played *Mountain Tigers* (3) scoring 442 to Tiger's 342

My question is how to parse this blocks of data in the most efficient way possible such that each club's data will be in the format below considering that a club's name may comprise of two (2) or more words.

Viz

[Club Round Score Opponent Opponent-Score] for each club

Comment: I have to ask... this is a very "homework" looking problem.  On StackOverflow [we don't care](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) *(though I might personally suggest that the question would be a better question if it contained more "what have you tried already")*.  I'm just more curious who's assigning Rebol homework, if they are, and if not where the problem comes from...

Comment: This is no homework I assure you. I'm new to Rebol and just testing out how easy/difficult it'd be to do things I can do easily say in PHP in Rebol (and learning at the same time). Besides who'd give a 40+yr old a homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `data` is:

```
data: [
    Hotspurs Giants 356 6 275 4 442 3
    Fierce Lions Club 371 3 2520 5 0 4
    Mountain Tigers 2519 2 291 6 342 1
    Shooting Stars Club 2430 5 339 1 2472 2
    Gun Tooters 329 4 2512 2 2470 6
    Banshee Wolves 301 1 2436 3 412 5
]
```

I think this solves the problem, please check the result:

```
clubs: copy []
parse data [
    some [
        copy club some word!
        copy numbers some number!
        (append clubs reduce [form club numbers])
    |
        skip
    ]
]
new-line/all/skip clubs yes 2

list: copy []
parse clubs [
    some [
        set club string! into [
            copy numbers some number! (
                i: 1
                foreach [score index] numbers [
                    append list reduce [
                        club score
                        pick clubs index * 2 - 1
                        pick pick clubs index * 2 i
                    ]
                    i: i + 2
                ]
            )
        ]
        | skip
    ]
]

new-line/all/skip list yes 4
```

Afterwards if you `probe clubs` you should get:

```
CLUBS is a block of value: [
    "Hotspurs Giants" [356 6 275 4 442 3]
    "Fierce Lions Club" [371 3 2520 5 0 4]
    "Mountain Tigers" [2519 2 291 6 342 1]
    "Shooting Stars Club" [2430 5 339 1 2472 2]
    "Gun Tooters" [329 4 2512 2 2470 6]
    "Banshee Wolves" [301 1 2436 3 412 5]
]
```

And if you `probe list` the output is:

```
LIST is a block of value: [
    "Hotspurs Giants" 356 "Banshee Wolves" 301
    "Hotspurs Giants" 275 "Shooting Stars Club" 339
    "Hotspurs Giants" 442 "Mountain Tigers" 342
    "Fierce Lions Club" 371 "Mountain Tigers" 2519
    "Fierce Lions Club" 2520 "Gun Tooters" 2512
    "Fierce Lions Club" 0 "Shooting Stars Club" 2472
    "Mountain Tigers" 2519 "Fierce Lions Club" 371
    "Mountain Tigers" 291 "Banshee Wolves" 2436
    "Mountain Tigers" 342 "Hotspurs Giants" 442
    "Shooting Stars Club" 2430 "Gun Tooters" 329
    "Shooting Stars Club" 339 "Hotspurs Giants" 275
    "Shooting Stars Club" 2472 "Fierce Lions Club" 0
    "Gun Tooters" 329 "Shooting Stars Club" 2430
    "Gun Tooters" 2512 "Fierce Lions Club" 2520
    "Gun Tooters" 2470 "Banshee Wolves" 412
    "Banshee Wolves" 301 "Hotspurs Giants" 356
    "Banshee Wolves" 2436 "Mountain Tigers" 291
    "Banshee Wolves" 412 "Gun Tooters" 2470
]
```

Comment: This solution should work for any number of matches. I especially did not change the data you gave but normally it is better to have club names as string in the first block instead of words.

Comment: Right on point endo64! This is what I wanted. You are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example (using Rebol 3) showing how this could be done:

```
club-data: map []  ; store data in hash map is one option

foreach line read/lines %games-scores.txt [
    fields: split line space

    ; lets take last 6 cols of data
    scores: reverse collect [loop 6 [keep to-integer take/last fields]]

    ; and whats left is the club name
    club-name: form fields

    ; build club data
    club-data/(club-name): scores
]
```

Above assumes data is in file `games-scores.txt` and returns you a MAP! (hash map) called `club-data` where your club data would look like this:

```
make map! [
    "Hotspurs Giants" [356 6 275 4 442 3]
    "Fierce Lions Club" [371 3 2520 5 0 4]
    "Mountain Tigers" [2519 2 291 6 342 1]
    "Shooting Stars Club" [2430 5 339 1 2472 2]
    "Gun Tooters" [329 4 2512 2 2470 6]
    "Banshee Wolves" [301 1 2436 3 412 5]
]
```

One caveat...  READ/LINES will load whole file into memory.  So if `games-scores.txt` is big you should look at using OPEN instead and read in one line at a time.

**Update** - re: your comment here is same example in Rebol 2 [tested in REBOL/Core 2.7.8.2.5 (2-Jan-2011)]:

```
club-data: make hash! []  ; of course doesn't have to be hash!

foreach line read/lines %games-scores.txt [
    fields:    parse line none
    scores:    reverse collect [loop 6 [keep to-integer take/last fields]]
    club-name: form fields
    append club-data reduce [club-name scores]
]
```

Comment: Okay..but perhaps I should have mentioned that I wanted a Rebol 2 solution. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Fortunately it doesn't take much to produce a Rebol 2 version - see my update to question.

Comment: One thing however, I see you are assuming all the 6 columns of integer data are scores but they are actually supposed to be score and opponent (index) in succession as explained above. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes I was just providing a solution to *parsing* the data thinking that this was your main hurdle you were trying to jump over.  Glad it helped and good to see endo64 has provided you with a complete answer.